# Let $X = C[0,1]$ and fix $v \in X$. Find $\sigma(T)$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $X = C[0,1]$ and fix $v \in X$. Define $T:X \rightarrow X$ such that $T(x) = vx$. Find $\sigma(T)$.

What I know so far.

Let, $\lambda \in \sigma(T)$. We have, $T_\lambda(x) = (T - \lambda I)x =  (v - \lambda)x.$ Now, I can have  $T_\lambda(x)$ to be one-one or not and accordingly I will obtain $\lambda$ in point spectrum or not. I am not sure, if this is even helpful.

Please, help me out. Thanks

Comment: If $T_\lambda$ has an inverse, you expect it to be $R_\lambda(x)=(v-\lambda)^{-1}x$. In particular we would need $R_\lambda(1)=(v-\lambda)^{-1}$ to be in $C[0,1]$. So, for sure  when $\lambda$ is in the range of $v$ that function won't be continuous. On the other hand, if $\lambda$ is not in the range of $v$, then it is bounded away from the range of $v$, since this is compact. So, $(v-\lambda)^{-1}\in C[0,1]$.

Comment: @plop I am not quite sure I understand you. I mean what can you conclude from this ? What $\sigma(T)$ needs to be ?

Comment: @plop What do you mean by: "If $\lambda$ is not in the range of $v$ then it is bounded away from the range of $v$".

Comment: Well, for sure if $\lambda$ is in the range of $v$, then we cannot invert $T_\lambda$. Then we are expecting to prove that $\sigma(T)=\operatorname{range}(v)$.

Comment: If $\lambda\notin\operatorname{range}(v)$, then there is $\epsilon>0$ such that for all $t\in[0,1]$ we have that $|v(t)-\lambda|\geq \epsilon>0$. This is because $\operatorname{range}(v)$ is compact. This is what I mean by $\lambda$ being bounded away from $\operatorname{range}(v).$